# Mac OS X: easiest (free, non-QuickTime Pro) application for converting numbered folder of images to movie

Tags: macos, mac, graphics

I'd like to convert a folder of PNGs into a quicktime .mov with [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) compression (it's a folder of fractals in an animation; PNG compression works great here and the losslessness is important). What programs will do this with minimal fuss? (I don't have or want to pay for a full license of [QuickTime Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickTime#QuickTime_Pro).)

UPDATE:

Let me make this more clear: minimal fuss means: I download some EncoderMagic.app (for example), I double click it to launch it. I select the folder with my numbered images, and out pops my movie. No mess. No resizing. ... Perhaps this doesn't exist (or is called QuickTime Pro?)

Comment: Possibly of no interest or help to you, but I understand that 'QuickTime Pro' as we currently know and love it is going to become just 'QuickTime', fully-featured and bundled as part of Snow Leopard - in others words, included with the OS.

Comment: I thought I'd heard that. It will make this problem go away, hopefully... I'll keep a heads up for it in the next few months. Thanks.

Comment: I used VirtualDub in Windows and accomplished my task but I'd still like to do this on my Mac if possible in the future (you know, since Macs have this reputation for being good at video and making movies). I guess I can wait for Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a freeware AppleScript-based application by the name of **Sequimago** which should fulfill your requirements admirably. It is available from [this page](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=25547) at *MacScripter*, a forum site where Martin Michel, Sequimago's author, is an administrator.

This is his description of the program:

> *Requirements*
>   Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard •
>   QuickTime 7.2.1
>
> *Installation & Usage:*
>   Download and
>   extract the ZIP archive. Then open the
>   script with a double click or drop a
>   bunch of image files onto its icon.
>   The script will then ask you to
>   specify a file name and location for
>   the new QuickTime movie. After you
>   provided certain settings for your
>   image sequence (e.g. frames per
>   second/seconds per frame), your image
>   sequence will be produced.
>
> *Supported Image Formats:*
>   jpg, jpeg,
>   gif, png, tiff, tif, psd, pict, bmp,
>   pdf (only the first page of a PDF
>   document is recognized)
>
> *Notes:*
>   Sequimago currently uses the
>   JPEG image format for the image
>   sequence, which results in a smaller
>   file size of the QuickTime movie. But
>   you can easily edit the Python script
>   to use alternative image formats (e.g.
>   TIFF). The Python script is located
>   at: Sequimago.app/Contents/Resources/crtimgseq.py

### - - - - - - - -

P.S. -- I think you'll appreciate a comment he made in the course of explaining how he came to write the program:

> I knew that you could easily create
>   custom slide shows with QuickTime Pro,
>   but why spent hard-earned $29.99 when
>   you can get the same functionality
>   free of charge by using built-in Mac
>   OS X 10.5 technologies?

Comment: That did the trick. I will have to play with the encoding (png will look better for this, I think...)

Comment: This app didn't work for me.  Well it worked, but i could not change the speed of the frames no matter what i put into frames per second. and when i tried seconds per frame it created a 64kb movie and then crashed.

Comment: Sequimago still working brilliantly on OSX Mavericks...

Answer (score 25):

The [ffmpeg command line tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20100804163214/http://www.macosxhints.com:80/article.php?story=20061220082125312) does this:

```
ffmpeg -n -i "image_%03d.jpg" output.m4v
```

`ffmpeg` will, in this example, look for files matching the pattern `image_xxx.jpg` in the current directory where the `xxx` part is a zero-padded decimal number, like `003`.  `ffmpeg` automatically chooses the output format based on the suffix of the output file, e.g., `m4v`.

Change `-n` to `-y` if you want ffmpeg to always overwrite output file without asking (useful for repeated tests).

I suggest you download `ffmpeg` from either [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/).

Comment: I recently had to go about doing the same. Clearly the command line isn't as easy as a GUI, but once I got to know it ffmpeg let me do exactly what I wanted, no matter what I wanted to do!

Comment: @dan I'd suggest Homebrew over the rather old Fink. It has more updates and works just as well. Nice edit though.

Comment: For anyone out there trying to use this and getting a black video, try adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` immediately before your output file name.

Comment: For more options (with description) check the related SU post: https://superuser.com/questions/356974/how-to-turn-images-into-a-video-slideshow-with-sound/356982#356982

Comment: Don't use the `-y` option above, as it overwrites files without prompting. Use `-n` instead, which halts if the output file exists. I made a mistake specifying input files, and overwrote all my source files!

Comment: If you want to use a `*` wildcard, add `-pattern_type glob` option before specifying input files, e.g. `ffmpeg -n -pattern_type glob -i 'image*.jpg' output.mpg`

Comment: For reference, the ffmpeg docs are here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html

Comment: @JimBergman sorry about that and thanks for the warning, I updated the answer

Answer (score 5):

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (available from macports) can do that, try running the command

```
convert -delay 30 'pic-*.png' movie.m4v
```

where 30 is the hundreths of seconds between frames and the files follow the pattern:

`pic-001.png pic-002.png ...`

Comment: Didn't work. It made a single frame movie. (ImageMagick 6.1.8 03/22/06). I even renamed the files to pic-*.png and it still only puts the first frame.

Comment: odd, it works on mine (ImageMagick 6.5.2-9 2009-06-03)

Comment: @Jared it's pretty old an ImageMagick you're having.. try a newer version

Answer (score 1):

[Framed](http://likelysoft.com/framed/) - it's free.

- Create sequences of any size with a virtually unlimited amount of images, and using any number of frames per second.
- Preview images by double-clicking them, and reorder them if need be.

[image]

Comment: Requires stuffit expander and no longer works in 10.8+ due to OSX removing rosetta support for PPC applications.

Answer (score 1):

[ImageJ](http://rsb.info.nih.gov/ij/) is a powerful GUI-based image editor/viewer/analyzer that, among many other things, lets you make movies from sequences of images. It meets your requirements, and provides useful options such as resizing, rotating, etc. if you want/need that.

Answer (score 1):

For me [time laps assembler](https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33252/time-lapse-assembler%20%22time%20laps%20assembler) does the trick.
It only takes .jpg as input but I can live with that for my animation. Besides of that I just tested it and it works fine!

Comment: Doesn't work with Mojave.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a slideshow? You can export a slideshow in movie format from iPhoto. It may be possible to set a slide transition time down to a second or less and make a movie-ish file that way.

Comment: Not in this case... I'm trying to turn 1000 frames into a 30 frame/sec 33.3 sec movie.

Comment: +1 great solution (except in this case)

Answer (score 0):

You could try iMovie. Just drag the files you want into the iMovie window, and it should be able to create a movie for you.

Answer (score -1):

mencoder, an encoder that comes with mplayer probably knows how to do that.

Comment: Useful in theory, but 'menncoder' does not exist in the (unofficial) pre-compiled binary package. In short: No yak-shaving. I'd like to make a movie, not compile source code. (Unless that is the easiest thing out there...)

Comment: You can have your yaks shaven (with conditioner and a massage) by Fink or MacPorts...