# How to save a series of JPGs as an AVI at 30fps?

Tags: video, video-conversion, jpeg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to turn images into a video slideshow with sound](https://superuser.com/questions/356974/how-to-turn-images-into-a-video-slideshow-with-sound)

I have a series of JPGs that were from a video file.  They are named according to their frame number.  How can I put them together into an AVI file at 30fps or 40fps (user specified)?

Comment: The idea is the same, just leave out the soundtrack and `map` options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `mencoder` and `ffmpeg` support using a set of JPEG images as their input. As AVI is a container, depending on whether it supports the codec, you can even make an MJPEG movie (which should almost literally correspond to stacking the JPEG images as frames inside the AVI container).

But, unless you have very strict quality requirements, it'll probably be way easier if you just try one of the default or more common codecs.

It has been some time since I did this for the last time, but browsing the web, it seems that [making a movie out of frames](http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/ffmpeg/) can be as simple as issuing a command like

```
ffmpeg -r 40 -i %d.jpg video.avi
```

Where, `-r` sets the framerate. Here, this outputs a divx video stream by default. But of course you can specify another video codec (or another container).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something under windows with a graphical user interface you can use Photolapse:

http://home.hccnet.nl/s.vd.palen/index.html

It worked for me to create a HD video out of 5000 JPG frames. The nice thing about this software is that you can preview the frames in the same interface and exclude selected frames from the movie.